# Keep only newest N rows in Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

I am repeatedly doing an operation which creates a record in my Cassandra table at every iteration. However, for my purposes I only need a limited number of the most recent results stored. Stale rows are not interesting, and also the database would quickly inflate in size because the operation is meant to run many times a second over many days.

I am essentially using the Cassandra table as a buffer. That is by design.

Is there a way to set Cassandra to have a limit on how many rows a table can have, and drop old rows automatically with minimum performance impact when new rows are pushed?

My codebase is in Python so I'd prefer a Python solution.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such method built-in.

The traditional approach in Cassandra is for removing old information is not by count, but rather by date: When you insert a row (or even modify a single cell), you can put an **expiration time** (a.k.a. **TTL**) on this data. E.g., you write a row that is set to expire on one day. Cassandra will then take care of dropping the expired data from disk - automatically and efficiently (actually dropping the data happens during compaction).

This is of course not the same as saying you always want to keep exactly the newest 1000 rows, but maybe this is good enough for your use case, if your main intention is to keep your database size from exploding, and not really to keep a specific number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cassandra as buffer or message queue is an anti-pattern (official documentation [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets)). If you will have many deletions you will end up with may tombstone records and the performance of the system will be hit in garbage collection of the tombstones.

Also, tombstones will keep occupying space for some time.

I suggest using Kafka or MySQL or RDS as explained [here](https://segment.com/blog/introducing-centrifuge/)

Otherwise, if you wish to continue using Cassandra only, you can have the timestamp of record creation as a clustering key and you will have to scan the complete table and then filter top N records

Comment: Note that if the time is a **clustering** key, not a partition key (this only makes sense if you have a lot of partitions for another reason - e.g.., a lot of separate input streams), then you don't need ALLOW FILTERING to find the top N - the records are already sorted by the clustering key, and all you need to do to find the top N is to set a LIMIT on the read to N (you'll want the clustering key to be sorted in DESCending order, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Use can use **TTL**. It will automatically delete the rows as the time mentioned in TTL